# Interactive HTML integrated as 2D-Element in A-Frame

Tags: aframe, webvr

I'm planning to make an 3D-WebApp with A-Frame and wanted insert an HTML page inside of it. 
Is it possible to add an HTML (with buttons and forms) as a 2D-Element within a 3D scene and interact on that with 2D-mouse interactions ?

I saw this but I seems that it can only display the HTML and not iteract with it.
https://github.com/mayognaise/aframe-html-shader

Answer (score 1):

Not really unless you just want to overlay an I-Frame (http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/CSS3D.html) or div onto the scene, it won't be part of the 3D scene, but you'd be able to click on it with mouse.

https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/introduction/faq.html#how-do-i-display-lt-iframe-gt-s-or-render-html-in-a-frame

Comment: Maybe this might work, they integrate a browser inside of A-Frame https://github.com/shaneharris/aframe-in-app-browser

Comment: you'd need something installed in the background and running locally. more an experiment than something that can be deployed.

Comment: you could try to position the div *in the scene* (in reality only as overlay) - and try to use some css to tweak [the 3d representations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transforms/Using_CSS_transforms#3d_specific_css_properties) to look like *embedded*...